# jena packages in jsp

Tags: jsp, jena

i imported Jena packages into my JSP page.

```
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDatatype" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.DatatypeProperty" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.Individual" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager" %>
```

When I run it, the error will prompt:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 9 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDatatype resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 10 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.DatatypeProperty resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 11 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.Individual resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 12 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass resolves to a package
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: it'l sort out some example that i did it in separate JAVA class.

Comment: problem solved :::  web-inf/lib folder is empty.. we have to copy jar files in to it ..:: :)

Comment: You should then post this as an **answer** yourself and accept it. Further, writing Java code in a JSP file is an extremely bad practice. [How to avoid Java code in JSP files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: nope.. i did lot of works with separate class and it' l give the error. then i did it in JSP and the error was same.. after that i put did it correctly.. any way thanks for your reply...